# Given two objects s1 and s2 of a struct which only contains Boolean type members, check if each member of s2 is true whenever the member of s1 is true

Tags: c++

I've got a struct `S` which contains only elements of a single Boolean type `Bool`. These elements are not stored in an array. So, the struct is of the form `struct s { Bool a, b, c, ... };`.

Now, I've got two objects `o1` and `o2` of type `S` and I need to have a function `test` which does the following:

```
bool test(S o1, S o2)
{
    if (o1.a && !o2.a)
        return false;
    if (o1.b && !o2.b)
        return false;
    if (o1.c && !o2.c)
        return false;
        
    ...
        
    return true;
}
```

Is there any better way to do that? The struct `S` might change in the future (i.e. some fields may be added; others may be removed) while `test` should perform the same work.

We could, for example, `reinterpret_cast` `&o1` and `&o2` to pointers of type `Bool*`  and perform the check, but maybe there is a better option.

(Note that `S` is given by a library that I'm using and hence I cannot change its definition.)

Comment: What is `Bool`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat As I said, some type which is is interpreted as a boolean type. In my concrete case, `Bool` is `uint32_t`.

Comment: My answer doesn't look like a good idea to me anymore, so I deleted it. Not sure if `reinterpret_cast`ing into `Bool *` is well-defined, but it should work.

Comment: Any template magic you attempt to use to consolidate this is just going to make it less readable. I'd say that, without control over the object definition, this is the best you're going to be able to do.

Comment: If you can manage the alignment issues, make it a union, one of whose members is like S, and the other one an array of the appropriate size: then, just loop over the array.

Comment: *"These elements are not stored in an array."* Create a `std::array<Bool /*&*/, N> toArray()` method.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any better way to do that?

Nope. Just write the code.

> The struct S might change in the future (i.e. some fields may be added; others may be removed) while test should perform the same work.

Then you'll have to check the correctness of the implementation of every function which touches one of those fields, including your test method, anyways.

> We could, for example, reinterpret_cast &o1 and &o2 to pointers of type Bool*

So that the code becomes brittle, relying on unportable undefined behaviour and working mostly by accident?  That seems like a cost that is not borne out by the tiny benefit of someone not having to *maybe* change a method *maybe* sometime in the future.

Just write sensible code like a sensible programmer and don't mess around with crazy tricks that buy you nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Since my other answer hasn't gone down well, you could also use boost fusion:

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/sequence.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct S
{
  bool a;
  bool b;
  bool c;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(S,
  (bool, a)
  (bool, b)
  (bool, c)
)

using namespace boost::fusion;

int main()
{
  S foo = {true, false, false};
  S bar = {true, false, false};
  std::vector<bool> fooVec, barVec;
  for_each(foo, [&fooVec](bool b){ fooVec.push_back(b); });
  for_each(bar, [&barVec](bool b){ barVec.push_back(b); });

  bool result = true;

  for (int i = 0; i <fooVec.size(); ++i)
  {
    result = result && (fooVec[i] == barVec[i]);
  }

  std::cout << result << '\n';
}
```

The only gotcha being you have to make sure the macro mirrors the struct.

Answer (score -2):

You could use a pointer to iterate over the members, I've used a regular `bool` but the principle is the same.

```
#include <iostream>

struct S { bool a; bool b; bool c; };

int main()
{
    S foo = {true, true, false};
    S bar = {true, false, false};

    bool* fooPtr = &foo.a;
    bool* barPtr = &bar.a;

    bool result = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(foo) / sizeof(bool); ++i)
    {
        result = result && (*(fooPtr + i) == *(barPtr + i));
    }
    std::cout<<result<<'\n';
}
```

This will only work if all members of the struct are bool, or all the bools are stored contiguously in the struct. I don't know if it is guaranteed that there is no padding between members of a struct that are all the same type... but I would like to know a compiler that does insert padding in this case.

Comment: That's... nasty. I'd rather introduce extra code to check through those booleans manually than to try and iterate through them like this. Or copy them to a temporary array and then iterate.

Comment: A struct that contains members of only one type is essentially the same as an array? I don't see why this is problematic, especially when it would save a lot of maintenance.